# How to increase function speed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So, i have this function:

```
def scan_likes(my_list):
    count = {}
    for element in my_list:
        try:
            count[element] = 0
            book = requests.get('https://booksmania.com', header = element) #list, that i get from API, no need to remake this line
            for text in book:
                if 'ok' in text:
                    count[element] += 1
        except Exception:
            pass
```

So, the thing is that two lists: my_list and book are too huge, so the function takes a really long time. Is there any option how I can increase speed, maybe use something instead of for loop?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, the fasted way would having to not to do all these requests, but this depends on the other support something like listing books or whatever. The second option would be parallelise the requests, so that you do N requests instead of 1 and then aggregate the results.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see why it's slow? If most of the time is spent on `requests.get()`, your options for speeding it up are pretty limited. Maybe look into [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to do some of the work in parallel.

Comment: Maybe it is enough to only fetch only the head? if so, try - https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_head.asp

Comment: You could *vastly* speed up this function by replacing it with `return {}`.  `text` is always a single character, it cannot possibly contain `'ok'`, so no count ever gets incremented.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use aiohttp to gather multiple urls in parallel. Since I can't access booksmania.com I'm using https://github.com/alexwohlbruck/cat-facts as example

Here is the full code

```
import asyncio
import sys
import aiohttp
import requests

url = 'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random'

def get_sync():
    for i in range(1,10):
        requests.get(url)
        print('.')
    print()


async def aget(session, url):
    await session.get(url)
    print('.')


async def get_async():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(1,10):
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(aget(session, url)))

        # wait for all concurrently
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1]  == 'sync':
        get_sync()
    else:
        asyncio.run(get_async())
```

To run it make sure that you have python 3.7, requests (`pip install requests`), and aiohttp (`pip install aiohttp)` installed.

To run use `python3 multiple_request.py sync` to gather all requests with requests library, with no concurrency and `python3 multiple_requests.py async` to run the async version.

For each request that it mades it prints a dot in the output, so is possible to have a visual felling of how slow or fast it is.

Now the code..

The `get_sync` function is what is known, you simply iterates over something and do the requests. No big deal,

The `get_async` function is what is interesting to us. Instead of awaiting for each request, I accumulate all *"Tasks"* in an array then wait for all them in parallel* with [asynio.gatther](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently)

But what is a Task?

A [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) is something that runs in background, and we use [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) to create them

To sum up, without getting to deep on asyncio, instead of running each request in series, we schedule all requests to run in background, and then wait for them all to complete.

**parallel: Well the technical term here is concurrently, not parallel. I just don't want to burden the explanation with one more concept.*

With this example you should be able to translate your problem to asyncio. Here is a nice blog post about it https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html

I hope it helps